# Get the id from database after clicking on a edit button in jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, datatables

When I click the delete button of a certain row, I need to get the id of that row from the database, so that once obtained that id can send it to the controller to delete that row.

I was trying to do it this way.

This is my HTML table.

```
<table id="tableClient" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>RUC</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And with jQuery DataTable i'm trying to do this:

```
var table = $('#tableClient').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": [0]
    },
    {
        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",
        "targets": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, ],
    "language":
    {
        "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
    },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":
    {
        "url": "/Mantenimiento/FiltrarClientesTablaAsync",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON",
    },
    "columns": [
    {
        bSortable: false,
        mRender: function (o) { return '<button type="button" onclick="delete(id);" class="btn btn-default delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /></button>'; }
    },
    {"data": "Name"},
    {"data": "LastName"},
    {"data": "RucClient"},
    {"data": "Phone"},
    {"data": "Email"}
    ],
});
```

The thing is when i click the delete button i want to call an onclick="delete(id);" event and send the id to that event that will delete the row of that id.
Any idea of how can i do this with jQuery and MVC?.

Comment: Couldn't you pass the ID for each client and put it in the DataTable when it is initially loaded? That way you already have it to perform your delete. You can keep it hidden if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work out what I needed.
I just had to add the data-atributte called data-id with the id of the database and then pass it as a reference with "this" to the delete method.

This is my solution:

```
"columns": [
    {
        data: null,
        bSortable: false,
        render: function (data, type, row) { return '<button type="button" onclick="delete(this);" class="btn btn-default delete" data-id="' + data.id + '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /></button>'; }
    },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in order to pass the value to the delete() function you have written.

```
{
    "data": null,
    "className": "class1 class2",
    "orderable": false,
    "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return '<button type="button" onclick="delete(' + data.Id + ');" class="btn btn-default delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" /></button>'; 
        // where data.Id is the Id of the entry in the row
    }
},
```